# sparql query is not returning desired output

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

This is my sparql query to get all the country name with some property of that country.

```
SELECT distinct ?country ?capital ?currency ?lat ?long
WHERE {
  ?country rdf:type dbo:Country .
  ?country  dbo:capital ?capital .
  ?country  dbo:currency ?currency .
 ?country   geo:lat ?lat.
 ?country   geo:long ?long.
}
ORDER BY ?country
```

But the problem is, Some country is missing, like "Switzerland". You go to http://dbpedia.org/page/Switzerland this page you will see that it's type is country. you will also do not find exactly "Austria" rather "Austrian_Empire". Why? There is a entity called "Austria" and it is dbo:Country type.

Answer (score 2):

Switzerland does not seem to have `dbo:capital`, which is why it's not included in the results of your query.

If you want to get even results that do not have some of the properties, use `OPTIONAL`:

```
SELECT distinct ?country ?capital ?currency ?lat ?long
WHERE {
  ?country rdf:type dbo:Country .
  OPTIONAL
  {
    ?country  dbo:capital ?capital .
    ?country  dbo:currency ?currency .
    ?country  geo:lat ?lat.
    ?country  geo:long ?long.
  }
}
ORDER BY ?country
```

Though this query returns even entities that are not countries (but for some reason are `dbo:Country`), like [Cinema of Switzerland](http://dbpedia.org/page/Cinema_of_Switzerland).

Comment: OPTIONAL is the way to go.